# Find a way to implement this summation

Tags: python, math, time-complexity

I have two arrays A, B, filled with n integers. I want to find a way to implement this summation:

```
Σ(k=2 to n-2) (B[k] * A[n-k])
```

but considering that I have to use this summation in a for loop that costs `O(n)`.

The problem is to find a way to re-use the previous result of the summation to save it in a variable and don't have to sum all the values in every loop.

I add the values in the two arrays:

```
[32, 164, 752, 3348, ...]
[10, 18, 38, 84, ...]
```

The values in A are filled thanks to this formula, so I can't use the summation in the xth iteration without fill the x-1 position of A.

Comment: Why can't you compute the sum outside the loop and use that result in the loop? Can you add more details about the issue you're facing? Maybe add the complete code as well?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [ask]. What have you already tried? SO is not a code-writing service, so please post your best attempt, regardless of whether it doesn't work or is slow (e.g. `O(n^2)`). Also include some example input and output. For reference see [mre] and [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341)

Comment: It's a summation for a problem of dynamic programming and I have to fill a table with these result (for every n the result of summation).

Comment: @wjandrea This is just a little part of a dynamic programming problem, but is just a for loop (for i from 0 to n+1 ) with the loop for summation inside.

Comment: You gave us a subproblem, that I am not sure can be optimized. You state you need to do this summation in a for loop, and that's expensive. But we have no idea how this for loop is behaving, and on what values (and ultimately, what you are looking for). Please provide more information about the problem at hand.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```py
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
B = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
sum(a * b for a, b in zip(A[-3: 1: -1], B[2: -2]))
```

`A[-3: 1: -1]` flips list `A` and does not take into account the 2 first and 2 last elements.

`B[2: -2]` does not take into account the 2 first and 2 last elements.

It will sum `5*3 + 4*4 + 3*5` and gives `46`.

Comment: But I have a for loop (O(n)) and do a sum into it takes me to O(n^2). Thank you, btw

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is to compute that sum before you start your other loop and store the result in a variable, e.g.

```
def my_sum(a, b):
    summation = 0
    for k in range(2, n-1):
        summation += b[k] * A[n-k]
    return summation

# and in your main code
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
b = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

c = my_sum(a, b)
for n in range(1000):
    do_something_with(c)
```

Now, none of that code is very pythonic, but I presume you are starting out, so aim for working code first, then fast or beautiful code.

If you want it to be more efficient in practice, you should have a look into [numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html), which provides faster operations than just using basic lists like what I show here. The function you are probably looking for is called `convolve` (and the operation you are looking for is convolution).

Do note that this kind of operation (or at least the direct implementation) is inherently `O(n^2)`, so you would need a better algorithm to get below that kind of behavior. The numpy docs already hint toward a faster algorithm using the Fast Fourier Transform. I'll leave that one up to you to look into :-)

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer, but I forgot to mention that all the previous elements in A are calculated by this formula (I added this in the post). I just can't do nothing (neither calculate summation) if I don't fill with its results the A array.

Comment: @Laban probably it helps if you write out the mathematics more clearly, because it is a bit vague. 
From the context, I would infer it looks like an IIR (infinite impulse response) filter; for which standard implementations exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
def somme(A,B):
  n = len(B)
  somme = 0
  for i in range(2, n-1):
      somme = somme + ( B[i] * A[n-i] )
  return somme
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a numpy array. It doesn't require creating the list of pruducts before the sum.

```
import numpy as np
A=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
B =[9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]
n = len(A)
k0 = 2 # start offset
n0 = 2 # end offset
A1 = np.array(A[k0 : n-n0])
B1 = np.array(B[-1-n0:-n+k0-1:-1])
answer = (A1*B1).sum()
```